# Cygwin mandatory for Hive on windows

Tags: hive, cygwin

I have set up Hadoop 2.5.2 on my windows 7 machine. The requirement is to load flat files on hadoop and process the data on the flat file and render a report out of it. Technologies decided are Hadoop 2.5.2, Spark and Hive. However in case of hive on windows we need to use Cygwin (becoz hive is developed for unix environment and to use it we need Cygwin). The question here is, can we use Hive on windows without Cygwin or do we have any other alternative for Hive on windows. 
The reason we don't want to use Cygwin is we need to have every installation and files under Cygwin.

Thanks,
Santha

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Have in mind the tutorials tell you to use cygwin for running the script because the Hive community got lazy before doing windows bat or cmd files.

Happens similarly with sqoop. It runs on windows but the windows scripts have some bugs.

Just configure hive on top of hadoop and the dependencies will be resolved. If you need to run commands you can do that in linux and then get the generated artifacts.

Answer (score -1):

Hadoop is  built on top of Linux. Linux being an open source, you can use linux libraries and other open source infrastructure to create new "open source" tools and systems.
It is on Linux that's why it is open source and free to download otherwise we had to pay good amount of money to buy it.
You can run Hadoop on windows also.

Apache Hadoop (2.2 onwards) supports windows, its still not deployed in that configuration.

Reasons:

1.Maturity of Apache Hadoop on Windows

2.Cost effectiveness ( imagine few k nodes X licensing)

3.That too for running an unsupported software!

4.This causes enterprises to shy away from Hadoop itself( CDH, HDP, MapR, Pivotal HD are filling that gap).

5.Those organizations who don't shy away from Apache Hadoop, don't do that for Linux either.

For Hive  download hadoop cluster from Cloudera like CDH3,4,5 which is built on a Linux OS.They already have hive installed.

Use VMware or any other to run machine by Cloudera in Windows.

Your requirement solution:

1st Option you can install hadoop yourself.(Google about it)

2nd Option use virtual machine by any of the vendors (Cloudera,Horton Works etc)
in that machine U can easily install hive but I think they provide basic tools that include hive also.

For Example,CDH3 by Cloudera provides the basic machine provides hive 0.8 (which is not latest)

Comment: Thanks for your response! As stated in my question I have already installed hadoop on windows and I want to install Hive on the same machine. Is it possible to use Hive with Cygwin ? Or do we have any other alternative to it.

Comment: Yes u can install hive on cygwin

Comment: Sorry there was a typo, I wanted to type will hive work without Cygwin?

Comment: No. Hive needs hadoop and  hadoop needs linux based enviroment.

Comment: This is because hive stores data in HDFS(hadoop file system) and metadata is stores using a RDMS. Google about Hive Structure  u get it more.